# Drupal 7 + Ubercart + layaway?

Tags: 7, ubercart

My boss was interested in creating a sort of layaway program for our company. Problem is, I've never heard of anything that would allow this using ubercart. Anyone have some UC recipe for creating the ability to have layaway?

I'm still searching for a way to create this functionality but the closest i've found to be able to do that is [Ubercart Funds](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart_funds). The problem is the module isn't stable and it doesn't seem to function correctly.

I've also seen [UC Recurring](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring) and this seems like it might have potential. I still need to do some testing on this.

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution for this? I have a similar need for a layaway / 3-pay option for our higher-priced products. In a perfect world, the solution would show only the payment options that can handle the split payment, would be available as an option in the cart only if certain products were in the cart, and would possibly add a small administrative fee to the order if the layaway/3-pay option were selected.

Comment: @hockey2112 I haven't found anything that will do what you and I both need. Sooo... I'm undertaking the task of building one that will hopefully work for ubercart.

Comment: Ah ok. Please do keep me posted if you are successful and you make it available for others to use (or to purchase from you).